# How to create geometry with geometry functions?

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

I see there are functions in QGIS that supposed to generate geometry, like `geom_from_wkt`. How do I actually display it?

When I create a new field (in a field calculator) with a formula, say

```py
bounds(make_line(make_point($x-1,$y-1),make_point($x+1,$y+1)))
```

its value becomes `NULL` no matter what type I select.

And If I say `Update existing field"` and choose `<geometry>` in the dropdown -- nothing changes, I still do not see rectangles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That expression returns an object of type *geometry*.
Therefore it is not possible to save its value (as written) in any columns of the attribute table.
However, the expression can be used:

- In the [Geometry by Expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisgeometrybyexpression) tool, from the Processing Toolbox.
- In the [Geometry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/style_library.html#id25) applied to the Symbology tab in the Layer Properties.
- In the creation of [Virtual Layers](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers).

---

*About your expression:*

It is assumed that you are applying that expression to a single-part point geometries layer.

If they are not points, it returns *NULL*. If they are multi-part points, it returns a square of *2 units* side, only for the first part of the collection.

Although you cannot use it as it is in the attribute table, you could modify it a bit so that it returns a text string that describes the generated geometry, known as Well-Known Text (WKT):

```
geom_to_wkt( bounds( make_line( 
  make_point( $x-1, $y-1),
  make_point( $x+1, $y+1))))
```

Test it in a *Text(String)* with *Output field length* of 500.

Comment: So, the answer, it seems, is I cannot create or overwrite a geometry attribute with these expressions in the existing layer which already has a geometry attribute. Instead, I have to use the alternatives you listed.

Comment: The expression takes the *X* and *Y* coordinates of a point, and with them it forms a polygon (after the transformation that the expression applies). You cannot easily save polygons in a points layer. However you can make the points "look like polygons", with that expression in the geometry generator of the styling. The other option is that you create a new polygon layer, be it a "real" layer with the Geometry by Expression tool or a virtual layer.